# Batch copy creation date in .MOV video file to created date

Tags: video, batch, metadata

I have hundreds of .MOV video files recorded with my iPhone. Their "created" and "modified" file dates are the date where I moved them over to a folder on my Mac. "Media information" in VLC confirms the original date of the recording is in the video files metadata. 
I'd like to batch copy every original date and time of the recording into the "created" date field of the video file. I use "A Better Finder Attributes 6" to do that exact same thing with pictures but it does not process video files for me. I downloaded ExifTool but feel lost as to how to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you on Linux ? Windows ? MacOS ?

Comment: I am on MacOS although I could do this on a windows computer if need be - files are on an external HD

Answer (score 0):

Your command in exiftool would most likely be this:
`exiftool '-FileCreateDate<CreateDate' '-FileModifyDate<CreateDate' -api QuickTimeUTC /path/to/files`

This copies the embedded `CreateDate` tag from the file into the two file time stamps.  According to the spec, the video `CreateDate` is supposed to be set to UTC, which the iPhone usually seems to do, though not all cameras set it correctly. The `-api QuickTimeUTC` is needed so that exiftool adjusts the time from UTC to local time when it gets copied. If the file time stamps are off by the time zone amount, then remove this option.

In order to write the `FileCreateDate`, exiftool needs `setfile` to be installed.  This may be installed by typing `xcode-select --install` in the Terminal.

This command creates backup files.  Add `-overwrite_original` to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.